# How does strength of boric acid solution increase in presence of salicylic acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

A while ago, I read that salicylic acid can make boric acid solution strongly acidic when it's added to it.

To my knowledge, I know that boric acid becomes a strong acid in presence of *cis*-diols (except ethylene glycol). I also know that it happens due to increased stability of conjugate base by chelation using polyhydroxy compounds.

But I can't really make out the case with salicylic acid. I will be really thankful if you could shed some light on this topic.

Comment: see: https://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v77-421

Comment: Why not ethylene glycol?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image: boric acid and salicylic acid]

Equilibrium will be far to the right, as a stable six membered ring is formed. The proton speaks for itself.

---

**References**: Queen, A. The kinetics of the reaction of boric acid with salicylic acid. *Can. J. Chem.* **1977,** *55* (16), 3035–3039 [DOI: 10.1139/v77-421](https://doi.org/10.1139/v77-421).

Answer (score 3):

By googling "boric acid salicylic acid"
I have found the salicylic acid acts like it was a diol toward the boric acid, but just 1:1.

https://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/abs/10.1139/v77-421